# Fullscreen PDF, Adobe Acrobat and other PDF viewers

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers

I want that my pdf opens in fullscreen mode by default and I use the following command :

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

This works fine when I open the pdf with Adobe Acrobat but does not work with Apple's Preview (the default pdf viewer on Mac OS) or with Skim (the free software alternative for Mac OS). Does anyone has a solution which would work with all kind of software ?

Comment: `Hyperref` documentation states that `pdfpagemode` *Determines how the file is opening in Acrobat*. Solution for Mac OS X probably is not via pdfpagemode.

Comment: @Pouya Why don't you write an answer? :)

Comment: @MarioS.E., I stated the obvious! Not sure if it is an answer to the question since it doesn't actually solves the problem. Do you think I should submit it as an answer?

Comment: @Pouya yes, you definitely should.  This way anyone looking for the same question in the future will be able to "google it", will serve as a reference within TeX.SE and finally, will help us "answer the unanswered" :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to achieve this by the use of

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
```

Section 3.7 of `Hyperref` documentation states that

> pdfpagemode Determines how the file is opening in Acrobat;

If there is a solution to your problem, it does not lie in `pdfpagemode`.